# Can i use aws-cli with assigning roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, aws-cli

What I meant to say is that can I use aws-cli without using access-key and passphrase by simply assigning roles to aws?

Comment: Where will you be running the command? If you are running it on an EC2 instance, then you can assign roles. If you are running on your own computer, you will will still need some credentials to 'assume' the role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Once you have the role defined, you can configure AWS CLI with

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config

[default]
region=eu-west-1

[profile demo]
region=eu-central-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/admin
source_profile=default
```

and use it as this

```
aws --profile demo s3 ls
```

Details are here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html

Comment: I think we don't need to perform the following configuration ~/.aws/config file. Its working fine for me.